# Control how linux deletes files

Tags: files, filesystems, kernel

What exactly happens when an application deletes a file?

Is there any way to control this behavior? Basically I want to `shred` instead of `rm` in all cases, but of course applications do not make calls to `rm`, I am guessing they interact directly with the kernel?? Would I have to modify the kernel to implement this feature?

Comment: Deleting a file ends up in the kernel's `unlink` system call (`man 2 unlink`). When you try to intercept that one, you need to watch out for specials (link count, file is still in use) before starting to wipe it.

Comment: @ott-- you should put this as an answer below. I was just about to submit something similar to this, and then saw this.

Comment: I'd suggest that instead of writing your own fs, or attempted to do this in the C library somehow, patch an existing filesystem. E.g., maybe take a look at http://lwn.net/Articles/462398/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? For journalling filesystems, shredding data is well nigh impossible; same for SSDs.

Comment: @derobert nice link, I guess I'm not the only person to have thought of this

Comment: @DeerHunter I want deleted files to be unrecoverable, given that an adversary has decrypted the filesystem.

Comment: @trideceth12 “I want to survive even if someone cuts off my head.” The answer is not to have your head cut off.

Comment: This may be a stupid suggestion, but why not make "rm" an alias for "shred"?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying to intercept all filesystem calls, what about encrypting the filesystem your data is stored upon?  Then, all of your data gains the benefit of being securely encrypted, including that which was deleted.

Comment: Encryption is vulnerable to social engineering. But yes I get your point.

Comment: @trideceth12 Not encrypting is vulnerable to technical engineering. [`shred` is useless in most circumstances](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50079/effectivity-of-shred-on-different-file-systems/66238#66238).

Comment: Okay from research it seems the consensus position is to encrypt the sensitive info separately, and then destroy the key when the information is to be deleted.  This prevents being compelled to reveal the key.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to go in to the C libraries as well as the filesystem kernel modules in order to catch all cases. Applications most often call a library routine that then calls a routine inside the filesystem module.

In short, the only reliable way to control this behavior is to write and use your own filesystem. I don't think you want to go there - I know I wouldn't.

Comment: Better than writing your own filesystem would be to patch an existing one, or [help one of the existing attempts](http://lwn.net/Articles/462398/)

Answer (score 0):

The `chattr` **s** attribute might work on *ext4*-filesystems. I did not bother up until now.

I used `wipe` in important cases manually up until now.