# Shred files in tmpfiles.d

Tags: tmp

After searching the tmpfiles.d, its seems like there is a limited number of option to erase the files/directories.
I want to totally erase the temporary directories with a shred like command, is there a way to trigger a script in the tmpfiles.d configuration or some hidden mecanism to use shred during tmp cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Call `systemd-tmpfiles --remove` to remove all contents of directories that are configured with a `D` or `R` and all files or directories that are configured with `r` or `R`.

From `man systemd-tmpfiles`:

```
   --remove
       If this option is passed, the contents of directories marked with D or R,
       and files or directories themselves marked with r or R are removed.
```

To be slightly less invasive, you could filter this to only directories that start with a prefix:

```
   --prefix=path
       Only apply rules with paths that start with the specified prefix. This option
       can be specified multiple times.

   --exclude-prefix=path
       Ignore rules with paths that start with the specified prefix. This option
       can be specified multiple times.
```

Or you could clean more often.  `--clean` will only remove temporary files that have expired (age has passed).  In the following example, running `systemd-tmpfiles --clean` will delete any contents of `/run/screens` that are older than `10d`.

```
# /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/screen.conf
# Type  Path           Mode   User   Group    Age    Argument
  d     /run/screens   1777   root   screen   10d    -
```

Note that this is already checked once per day by `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer`:

```
$ systemctl cat systemd-tmpfiles-clean.{timer,service}
[Unit]
Description=Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories
Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5) man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d

# /lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
[Unit]
Description=Cleanup of Temporary Directories
Documentation=man:tmpfiles.d(5) man:systemd-tmpfiles(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
After=local-fs.target time-set.target
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=systemd-tmpfiles --clean
SuccessExitStatus=DATAERR
IOSchedulingClass=idle
```

If that isn't aggressive enough for you, you could:

```
d /my/path 0755 user group  1h -
```

and create a drop-in to `OnUnitActiveSec=1h` the timer.

Alternatively, if you are running a service, check out the sandboxing options in `man systemd.exec`.  Things like `PrivateTmp=`, `RemoveIPC=` and `DynamicUser=` really make it possible to delete these things as soon as they are not needed anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your very precise answer, but my question was more about the deletion process. I know that I can manually clean the tmp files, but underlying this will call 'rm' command and not 'shred' command, so the files will not be securely erased from disk.

Comment: Shred is snake oil on modern hard drives and file systems. It being absolutely zero additional security. And it doesn't even begin to makes sense on SSDs.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50079/effectivity-of-shred-on-different-file-systems

Comment: https://back.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-guttman.html